# Connect to SFTP through my application

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I have to connect to a Secure FTP(SFTP) server through my application
thats mean users can not connect to my sftp server with another software (filezilla , winscp and ... )

just connected through my created software

thanks

Comment: Are there any other boundary conditions? Which language are you intending to use?

Comment: You're assuming your users won't hack your code to find out how you're connecting?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I didnt want my users connect to sftp server with using (filezilla , winscp and etc ) . I want my users connect to sftp just through my written software.

Comment: my written software by C#

Answer (score 0):

Just do not give anyone credentials to the server. Only your application will have them.